# Unexpected result from expression using &

Tags: javascript

Here if

```
document.write(eval("(2 == 2)"));
```

it prints **true**

And

```
document.write(eval("(2 == 2)&(5<10)"));
```

it prints **1**
Why not it always returns true or false.If conditions increases in string it gives 0 or 1.What is the way to get same type of result.

Comment: Since the issue isn't actually anything to do with `eval`, I've taken the liberty of modifying the title so that others may find this if they run into the same problem.

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder to correct me and for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prints `1` because you used the bitwise and operator (`&`) instead of the logical and operator (`&&`).

And because JavaScript is loosely typed it will treat the boolean value `true` as an int value of `1`, which you can check by invoking

```
document.write(eval("(2 == 2)+(5<10)"));
```

the result will be

```
2
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `&` isn't a logical operator, it's a [*bitwise* (numeric) operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.10). You probably meant `&&`, the [logical AND operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11).

Note that there's no reason for using `eval` in your code examples. (There's almost *never* any reason to use `eval`, there's almost always a better alternative — in this case, you don't even need an alternative.) Removing it would have exactly the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a bitwise operator and returns a number. Try `"(2 == 2)&&(5<10)"`